# Including C++ Header files with namespaces in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c++

I'm trying to use a C++ library in my iOS app and I'm wrapping the library in Objective-C++ code.

One of the header files my iOS app relies on is a C++ header file that declares a few datatypes (enums and classes) inside namespaces. When I include the C++ header iOS land, I get compiler errors about the namespace keyword not being recognized.

Short of creating Objective-C++ wrapper classes for all of the C++ namespaced versions, is there another way to bring over the C++ headers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only thing you can do is wrap your C++ header imports in an `#ifdef __cplusplus` directive, which guarantees that other Objective-C++ and C++ headers can see the values of those namespaced enums and data types.  There will always be some form of C++ header tainting if you use an unchecked include.